# Notification with openfire in android and ios

Tags: android, android-studio, xmpp, openfire, asmack

Developing an application for android and ios with openfire server with asmack(for android). successfully implemented all stuff(one to one chat also group chat). now stuck in how can I implement notification with openfire server specially users get offline, tried with google but it didn't help. Any help appreciate...

Comment: If you need to know about someone's presence (online, offline) then you need to users Rosters as such notifications are sent to roster contacts automatically by server if roster subscriptions are valid. If you are talking about google push, then that is not supported in Openfire unless you find some plugin online or custom changes in your openfire deployment.

Comment: how can openfire sent notifications to roster contacts automatically..?

Comment: Please look at XMPP RFC on Presence Subscriptions Section: https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#sub

Comment: Have you implemented this one..?

Comment: It's by default implemented in server, however, on client side (Android/iOS) it needs to be implemented. I am server side guy so no experience with client side.

Comment: ok brother thanks.. m client side guy :D

Answer (score 1):

- If B gets offline and you want A to know about it. Roster is the thing you need. When users subscribe to each other on roster, then When B goes online/offline, All users who subscribed to B will get to know.
- If B gets disconnected from your chat server and A sends some message, and you want to have a notification on B, then you need push notification here. As described by @ShoaibGondal  "If you are talking about google push, then that is not supported in Openfire unless you find some plugin online or custom changes in your openfire deployment.– Shoaib Ahmad Gondal"

Comment: yes i want to implement push nootification any help with plugin..!

Comment: Well as i have mentioned above, currently no official plugin is available for Push support. However, some alternatives might be available but you will have to scratch your head to understand the flow and to fix any blocker issues etc.
Just a quick google search, i found below options:
i) https://bitbucket.org/yedincisenol/openfire-xmpp-notification-plugin
ii) https://github.com/xinminlabs/openfire-apns-plugin
I haven't tested any of these, but pasted links for you in case you get some help from here.